# routing views on angular in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I need Angular routing the views on codeigniter, but when the first controller on CI load index with a "ng-view" they return a 403, and is not permissions (as far as I know).

controller CI

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Pages extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'array'));
    $this->load->library(array('form_validation','session'));
    $this->load->model('cadastro_model');
}
public function index(){
    $this->load->view('pages');
}
public function cadastro(){
    // validate form cadastro
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nome', 'NOME', 'trim|required|alpha|max_length[50]|ucwords');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'EMAIL', 'trim|required|max_length[255]|strtolower|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('login', 'LOGIN', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|is_unique[users.login]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha', 'SENHA', 'trim|required|max_length[32]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('senha-confirma', 'CONFIRMAÇÃO DE SENHA ' ,'trim|required|max_length[32]|matches[senha]');
    // send data to array
    if($this->form_validation->run()==true) {
        $infos = elements(array('nome','email','login','senha'), $this->input->post() );
        $this->cadastro_model->do_insert($infos);
    }

    $dados = array(
        'template' => 'cadastro' ,
    );
    $this->load->view('pages', $dados);
}
```

}

Controller Angular

```
angular.module('pages', [])

.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'application/views/home.php'
});
$routeProvider.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'application/views/login.php'
});
$routeProvider.when('/cadastro', {
    templateUrl: 'application/views/cadastro.php'
})
});
```

Comment: You could try and set the status to 200

Comment: On codeigniter I think your only able to route the controllers then the views load in the controllers.